# Add existing NodeJs (node, Express, monodb,...) project to existing a NX monorepo (Angular)

Tags: node.js, angular, monorepo, nx.dev

Has anyone experienced how to add an existing NodeJS API to an existing (Angular) Nx Monrepo?

Unfortunately the manual doesn´t help me so much
https://nx.dev/migration/manual

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't an out-of-the-box solution, well, not to my knowledge. The simplest way, is to use NX to create a new app of the type you want to put into your monorepo, and then manually copy over the code. Don't forget to copy the packages from your package.json on your node repo, to the top level repo of the NX repo

Comment: @Malcor  Thx a lot for the hint its a pity!

Answer (score 2):

The process of migrating a repo into your mono repo requires a few manual steps. I think there would not be a simpler way to do it.

Assuming your node project does not share files with your current monorepo, this should be the steps:

1. on your node repo, create a branch 'to-monorepo' and in it, move all the files to folders that match the nx folder structure and push the commits to it.
2. remove your `package.json` file (we will later merge it with the monorepo's one)
3. once the folders match the nx folder structure, time to merge into the monorepo. From the monorepo add the remote of the other repo

```
git remote add node-repo <your git repo's node url>
```

4. at the monorepo folder, checkout your master
5. run a `pull` to make the node repo branches be available in the monorepo

```
git pull
```

6. create a new branch 'merging-node-repo' on your monorepo.
7. merge the branch `node-repo/to-monorepo` into your `merging-node-repo` branch, [preserving the history](https://nx.dev/migration/preserving-git-histories):

```
git merge node-repo/to-monorepo --allow-unrelated-histories
```

7. push your new branch (all the code and its history will now be listed in this new branch)
8. remove the remote `node-repo` from your local monorepo configs

```
git remote rm node-repo
```

9. manually merge all the node repo's original `package.json` file dependencies into the monorepo's one, and run `npm install` from the monorepo. This way your `package-lock.json` file is updated. Once you are done, create a commit and push it.
10. this last step is more tricky. You have now to manually update the monorepo's config files to allow nx to start managing it. This is where the [link](https://nx.dev/migration/manual) you had in your question might help. Once you are done, create a commit and push it.

With these steps you can then merge your `merging-node-repo` branch into master.

I recommend you to create a separated nx workspace with a nodejs project on it. This helps you with having a baseline for all the necessary nx configurations and dependencies.
You might want to make sure your project works via nx commands from this separated workspace; this way you will have a better chance of getting configurations of your monorepo right.

Hopefully this gets you started.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I wrote and used to import multiple repos into a single monorepo, under whatever subdirectories are wanted, while maintaining commit history:

- https://github.com/marcuswestin/monorepo-merge

I've also found two other scripts that look like they might work, but I haven't tried them:

- http://choly.ca/post/git-merge-to-monorepo/
- https://github.com/ksindi/monoreaper